# Cannot mute my ringtone since recent update, will go down to 1 bar and no further

Tags: ios

Any ideas please? I have to put it on do not disturb, which is less convenient than pressing the volume button.

Comment: iPhone, iPad or iPod touch? Which model? Which version of iOS?

Comment: What's wrong with using the mute switch on the side?

Answer (score 2):

This is usual behavior for iOS. The ringtone-volume can't be set to zero. If you want it muted, you'll have to use the mute-switch.

Perhaps you're mistaking it with the volume for music, etc. (as soon as music is playing your side button will trigger 'volume' instead of 'ringer' - which can be set to 0).